# Adding drop shadows to shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, 3d-map, weather

How can I add a drop shadow to shapefiles and have them show up on another software?

I have weather radar, WSV3, and I created my own custom county map, but i'm wanting to add drop shadows to the map to make it look 3D, I guess you could say. How can I do that and have it save into the shapefile so it imports correctly into the WSV3 Radar Software?

Comment: Shapefiles only store the data not the style. In general styles are not portable across programs unless they both use a standard like SLD

Comment: so, essentially, I would need to create a style inside of QGIS?

Comment: Actually, you would only really need to create a style in WSV3

Comment: Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I've no idea but if that is what your question boils down to then please [edit] it

Comment: @IanTurton How would I create a style in WSV3?  I'm not sure that's possible